# subscript text in a locale .yml string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml

Is there any way of styling my en.yml text as per below...

```
en:
  ...
  phosphorus:     "lbs/ac of Phosphorus (P<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>)"
```

As you can see I want the numbers to be subscript text.

This text is used as a label in a form.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include HTML in your translations, your keys should end in `_html` or `.html` e.g.

`en.phosphorus.html` or `en.phosphorus_html` (I personally prefer the first version).

Rails will know not to HTML escape these strings.

Comment: That worked well, as .html didn't work I went with the t('.phosphorus').html_safe which worked a treat. Thanks

Comment: You would need to rename your key of course to this :

`en:
  phosphorus:
    html:  "lbs/ac of Phosphorus (P<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub>)"
`